# Glue ETL Job to move data from Glue Data Catalog to Aurora DB

Tags: etl, aws-glue

I wanted to check if we can run the ETL job, to load 1000 of Table created by crawler in Data Catalog to Aurora DB using Glue ETL.
If yes do we need to create 1000 Scripts to do the transformation or is there any other approach?